# How to categorise columns based on quantile range

Tags: pandas

[the dataframe sample image is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2470.png)Categorise the states into four groups based on the GDP per capita (C1, C2, C3, C4, where C1 would have the highest per capita GDP and C4, the lowest). The quantile values are (0.20,0.5, 0.85, 1), i.e., the states lying between the 85th and the 100th percentile are in C1; those between the 50th and the 85th percentiles are in C2, and so on.

I don't have any idea how should I approach this

- I have two columns, one state name another gdp values
- I have to categorise the states and get results

Answer (score 1):

[Source of GDP](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2019/01/weodata/weorept.aspx?sy=2018&ey=2018&scsm=1&ssd=1&sort=country&ds=.&br=1&c=512%2C668%2C914%2C672%2C612%2C946%2C614%2C137%2C311%2C546%2C213%2C674%2C911%2C676%2C314%2C548%2C193%2C556%2C122%2C678%2C912%2C181%2C313%2C867%2C419%2C682%2C513%2C684%2C316%2C273%2C913%2C868%2C124%2C921%2C339%2C948%2C638%2C943%2C514%2C686%2C218%2C688%2C963%2C518%2C616%2C728%2C223%2C836%2C516%2C558%2C918%2C138%2C748%2C196%2C618%2C278%2C624%2C692%2C522%2C694%2C622%2C962%2C156%2C142%2C626%2C449%2C628%2C564%2C228%2C565%2C924%2C283%2C233%2C853%2C632%2C288%2C636%2C293%2C634%2C566%2C238%2C964%2C662%2C182%2C960%2C359%2C423%2C453%2C935%2C968%2C128%2C922%2C611%2C714%2C321%2C862%2C243%2C135%2C248%2C716%2C469%2C456%2C253%2C722%2C642%2C942%2C643%2C718%2C939%2C724%2C734%2C576%2C644%2C936%2C819%2C961%2C172%2C813%2C132%2C726%2C646%2C199%2C648%2C733%2C915%2C184%2C134%2C524%2C652%2C361%2C174%2C362%2C328%2C364%2C258%2C732%2C656%2C366%2C654%2C144%2C336%2C146%2C263%2C463%2C268%2C528%2C532%2C923%2C944%2C738%2C176%2C578%2C534%2C537%2C536%2C742%2C429%2C866%2C433%2C369%2C178%2C744%2C436%2C186%2C136%2C925%2C343%2C869%2C158%2C746%2C439%2C926%2C916%2C466%2C664%2C112%2C826%2C111%2C542%2C298%2C967%2C927%2C443%2C846%2C917%2C299%2C544%2C582%2C941%2C474%2C446%2C754%2C666%2C698&s=NGDPD&grp=0&a=&pr.x=32&pr.y=12)
Pay attention: the difference between qcut and cut. cut is to cluster by delta.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Country":["US","EU","China","Japan","Germany","UK","France","India","Italy","Brazil","Canada"],
                    "GDP":[20494050,18750052,13407398,4971929,4000386,2828644,2775252,2716746,2072201,1868184,1711387]})

df["qcut"] = pd.qcut(df["GDP"],4)
df["qcut_interval"] = pd.qcut(df["GDP"],4,labels=["pretty bad","bad","good","pretty good"])
df["cut"] = pd.cut(df["GDP"],4)
df["cut_interval"] = pd.cut(df["GDP"],4,labels=["pretty bad","bad","good","pretty good"])
df['delta'] = (df["GDP"] - df["GDP"].min()) / (df["GDP"].max() - df["GDP"].min())
df['delta'] = df['delta'].apply('{:.0%}'.format)

   Country       GDP                      qcut qcut_interval                        cut cut_interval delta
0        US  20494050   (9189663.5, 20494050.0]   pretty good  (15798384.25, 20494050.0]  pretty good  100%
1        EU  18750052   (9189663.5, 20494050.0]   pretty good  (15798384.25, 20494050.0]  pretty good   91%
2     China  13407398   (9189663.5, 20494050.0]   pretty good  (11102718.5, 15798384.25]         good   62%
3     Japan   4971929    (2828644.0, 9189663.5]          good  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad   17%
4   Germany   4000386    (2828644.0, 9189663.5]          good  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad   12%
5        UK   2828644    (2394473.5, 2828644.0]           bad  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad    6%
6    France   2775252    (2394473.5, 2828644.0]           bad  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad    6%
7     India   2716746    (2394473.5, 2828644.0]           bad  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad    5%
8     Italy   2072201  (1711386.999, 2394473.5]    pretty bad  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad    2%
9    Brazil   1868184  (1711386.999, 2394473.5]    pretty bad  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad    1%
10   Canada   1711387  (1711386.999, 2394473.5]    pretty bad  (1692604.337, 6407052.75]   pretty bad    0%
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) with specify quantiles:

```
df["q"] = pd.qcut(df["GDP"], q=[0,.2,.5,.85,1])
df["labels"] = pd.qcut(df["GDP"], q=[0,.2,.5,.85,1], labels=['C1','C2','C3','C4'])
```